# Pagedown markdown editor and using html div

Tags: markdown, pagedown

I'm using the page down editor from here: http://pagedown.googlecode.com/hg/demo/browser/demo.html (I think it's roughly the same as this one in Stack Overflow.

I'm trying to add formatting for Bootstrap just by inputting div. I'm using the "unsanitized" version (option 2) in the demo. I've tried in my local, and in this demo site but whenever I add the div's around the content, the preview parsing breaks.

It's very easy to replicate the problem, just go to the demo above, and in the second dialog, enter the code below.

Does anyone know how to fix? (other than not using div's in the code)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">

This is the *second* editor.
------------------------------
### hello

## hello

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that pagedown interprets the contents of a HTML `div` also as HTML. This works:

```
<div>
  <strong>foo</strong>
</div>
```

While this, unfortunately, doesn't.

```
<div>
  **foo**
</div>
```

So unless I'm missing a config option, you'll have to choose a different markdown processor like for example [commonmark.js](https://github.com/jgm/commonmark.js) ([example](http://spec.commonmark.org/dingus.html?text=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22row%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22col-md-12%22%3E%0A%0AThis%20is%20the%20*second*%20editor.%0A------------------------------%0A%23%23%23%20hello%0A%0A%23%23%20hello%0A%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E)).

Comment: is there any link that explains how to swap out the markdown processor?